# Jquery. click event doesn't work after change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

Having this sample code:

```
<input type="text" id="changeid">
<a href="#" id="clickb">click</a>

<script>
    $('#clickb').on("click", function(event){
        alert(1);                             
        return false;
    });

    $('#changeid').on("change", function(event){
        alert(2);                             
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

When putting something into the text field and click the link immediately, only onchange event fires, but not link click event.
Why is that?
It seems that the change event is blocking the click event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you edit the input and then click on the link the following happens on the inside

1. You start clicking on the 'link'. No events are generated yet (not even mousedown), because first the browser will do some cleanup work:
2. The input loses focus  and will raise a `blur` event
3. The input raises a `change` event, since it raised a `blur` and the value changed
4. Your `change` event callback opens an `alert(2)`
5. The documents loses focus since a new window appeared
6. The link will never experience the `click`.

The solution is not to use `alert` (as xdazz proposed).

Comment: Came here with the same problem, but different preconditions.  It's worth noting that the same explanation is in play when using a script debugger to highlight change and click events

Answer (score 11):

It is blocked by `alert`. Change `alert` to `console.log` you will find two events all fired.

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/CFUcz/)***

```
$('#clickb').on("click", function(event){
    console.log(1);
    return false;
});

$('#changeid').on("change", function(event){
   console.log(2);                             
   return false;
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$("#changeid").live('change', function () ...
```

Answer (score 0):

onchange event fires only after the element is blurred. So when u type some text and click on the link first the element is blurred on the text field. The best way to handle the change event on having onkeyup event to track the changes made on the text field.